# Checking elements existence under the cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use `javascript` to detect if an element exists under the cursor of the mouse, meaning that for example I want to check if I was on an "img" or if i was on a "p" element.

I don't want to add a hover method, the application does dragging and dropping of elements, and while dragging, I want to deny the dropping of that element in an area where another element exists.

Is it possible using `javascript/jQuery` and `html` ? and what would be right way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it:

```
window.onmousemove = function(e){
    var e = e || event;
    var all = document.all;
    for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++)
        if(e.x>=all[i].offsetLeft && e.x<=(all[i].offsetLeft+all[i].offsetWidth) && e.y>=all[i].offsetTop && e.y<=(all[i].offsetTop+all[i].offsetHeight)){
            //Do something
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: so what you mean is that i check for that width and the height of the element and the position I am in now and see if i was in ani of its Xs or Ys ?

Comment: No, the mouse's position must be between the element's limits. These limits are defined by it's position x to position x+width, for example

Comment: Thanks Alot for the help. :), very neat and to be recommended answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are asking can be set in the options of jQueryUI draggable and droppable interaction methods. If the current draggable system isn't set up for simple user options coding, take a look at these.

There are events built in like the "over" you mention. You can set droppables to only accept certain elements using simple jQuery selectors or callbacks. The API is robust and there is great support for it

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/